# How to group elements in structures, count them and calculate a sum in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures

This is probably a simple question. I am reading csv file with two columns: name + value. I can have a lot of entries there. What is the easiest and most efficient way to count occurrences of each 'name' + sum of values? I can do it on my own with loops but probably there is some smart way in Python to do this.

Example:

```
adam;10000
bartek;1000
tomasz;5000
adam;1000
bartek;3000
```

Result:

```
adam;11000;2
tomasz;5000;1
bartek;4000;2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module for this. Read the data from your file into a dictionary - use the name as key and store values in a list under this key. Using the [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) is easiest:

Write data file:

```
name = "f.txt"
with open(name, "w") as f:
    f.write("""adam;10000
bartek;1000
tomasz;5000
adam;1000
bartek;3000""" )
```

Process data file:

```
import csv # https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html
from collections import defaultdict

# read data into dictionary
results = defaultdict(list)
with open(name, newline='') as f:
  reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=";")
  for line in reader:
      if line:
          results[line[0]].append(int(line[1]))

print(results)

# write data from dictionary to file
with open("new" + name, "w", newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=";")
    for key in results:
        writer.writerow([key, sum(results[key]), len(results[key])])


# read file and print it
print(open("new"+name).read())
```

Output:

```
# read data
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'adam': [10000, 1000], 
                             'bartek': [1000, 3000], 
                             'tomasz': [5000]})

# written results
adam;11000;2
bartek;4000;2
tomasz;5000;1
```

Comment: Instead of using `defaultdict(list)` and `results[line[0]].append(int(line[1]))` and then calling `sum()` on the result, I suggest using directly `defaultdict(int)` and `results[line[0]] += int(line[1])`.

Comment: @stef - the output contains the sum of values AND the amount of summed values, `adam;11000;2` hence the defaultdict(list) - else I would need another dict to count up the amount of lines together.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data is inside a tupled list (and you don't/can't use pandas), you can do the following:

```
people = [('adam', 10000), ('bartek', 1000),
          ('tomasz', 5000), ('adam', 1000), ('bartek', 3000)]

report = {}
for person in people:
    name, salary = person

    # we initialize the counter
    if name not in report:
        report[name] = {'salary': 0, 'times': 0}

    # then we add to it
    report[name]['salary'] = report[name]['salary'] + salary
    report[name]['times'] += 1
```

Then you can retrieve each value using:

```
print(report)
print(report['adam'])
print(report['adam']['salary'])
print(report['adam']['times'])
```

Answer (score 0):

one of the most popular packages in Python to deal with data is Pandas. It will allow you to store your csv data (by a read_csv function) into a python object (called a Pandas Dataframe), and then apply multiple functions on it.

Once your data put onto a pandas dataframe (calling it `df`), you can do the following

```
df_result = df.groupby('name')['value'].sum().reset_index()
```

Doing that, you regroup your data by name, and calculate the sum of each value with the same name.